# Apache Spark partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I have this question:

If I perform a partitioning then perform an action such as
    reduce/fold, does it mean that the partitioning is undone and I will
    have to do a repartition after the action for better performance?

Comment: The first part of my two questions was answered. I edited that out.

Comment: If you are decreasing the number of partitions in this RDD, consider using coalesce, which can avoid performing a shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once data is partitioned, the partitions are maintained by Spark for further processing including transformation/actions unless you reparation or coalesce.

After partitions are created, each executor would allocate a task to run the transformation/action in a stage for the partition it is assigned to, and partitions (updated) move on from one stage to another stage for any transformations/actions

Answer (score 2):

Actions in Spark return

- Nothing (`None` in PySpark, `void` in Java, `Unit` in Scala) for actions used purely for side effects like `foreach`.
- Local, non-distributed object for other actions.

At the same time actions don't affect immutable objects or which there are called (with exception to possible side effects of caching, checkpointing, caching shuffle files and computing statistics).

Therefore partitioning is not really meaningful concept here.

Results are not Spark distributed data structures so partitioning doesn't apply, sources are not modified (and are descriptions, not containers anyway).